# What's a good Mac app for making timelines (Gantt charts)?

Tags: software-recommendation, mac, software

What's a good native Mac app for making timelines on Macs? I'm looking for an easy-to-use program that I can use to create timelines easily without delving into graphics programs like Illustrator. (Which I *can* use, but would be quite time consuming.)

Answer (score 14):

*Revised because of edited question...*

[OmniPlan](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniplan/) can create very nice looking Gantt charts and timelines out of project plan data. It is a full-on project planning tool, which might be overkill. But the output is quite lovely.

Comment: I use OmniPlan and really like it.

Comment: I second OmniPlan. Latest update works with 2007 and 2010 Project files, no one at work even notices that I work in another program. Omnigroup builds solid apps and they are working on an iPad version.

Comment: Yep, I have OmniGraffle but it is quite time intensive to create a timeline. (I was using OmniGraffle actually to create a timeline recently for a mini-project before.)

Comment: What I'm looking for, however, is an application that can create a event timeline... for example, one that would be used in History classes. (Dates, figures, ...)

Comment: @JFW: that's good info. I'd recommend the OmniGroup's other product for that: [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/). It's like Visio for Mac and I've drawn history-class type timelines (for s/w planning) with it.

Answer (score 5):

[Merlin](http://www.projectwizards.net/en/merlin/) is a fairly user-friendly tool for making Gantt charts. It's commercial software, so it is going to set you back. The interface is a clean "Mac" interface.

[OpenProj](http://openproj.org/openproj) is another possibility, and it is free.

Comment: I thought OpenProj was the answer to my Gantt needs, but the behaviour is just so quirky that i gave up.

Answer (score 3):

[Bee Docs Timelines](http://www.beedocs.com) might suit your needs. The marketing is towards the 3D functionality, but I've had good results generating 2D timelines. Doesn't do Gantt charts, though.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a replacement for MS Project for a long time. I haven't found an acceptable native app on the Mac that works well enough and opens/saves Microsoft Project files. The best i've found up to now is [Gantter](https://app.gantter.com/), which is web based and integrates with Google Docs. Surprisingly good.

For serious Gantt charts, nothing beats Microsoft Project, so i often end up running that in a virtual machine (Parallels) on my Mac. Oh the pain!

Answer (score 0):

Project Libre is the closest to MS Project.  Actually nothing is really close to MS Project.  But as a MS Project user, I find Project Libre file compatible and quick to use.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using TikiToki for a while and it is good for graphical timelines.  It has a Web App and desktop app.  There's a trial [here](http://www.tiki-toki.com/desktopapp/).  And the web app is here: http://www.tiki-toki.com

Another option is http://www.scribblecode.com Aeon Timeline which I have used the demo of and found good but haven't purchased yet.

Answer (score -1):

http://teamgantt.com   …   used by Oracle, Twitter, Sony. LeProf

Comment: This isn't native…