# software to create timeline from excel data for mac

Tags: mac, software-recommendation

I'm looking for a free or cheap product to create a timeline from an upload of an excel file, simple data (year and description). Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the difference between your question and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9503/whats-a-good-mac-app-for-making-timelines-gantt-charts ?

Comment: @patrix I was going to say the same thing, since the [original question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/revisions/9503/1) is almost identical to this one (without referring to the Excel file). However, since the edit referring to Gantt charts made to that question, a simple timeline of dates *is* a different question…

Comment: Fair point, I would nevertheless prefer if the OP could add some details on what they are looking for and maybe also include a sample image.

Answer (score -1):

### BEEDOCS [Easy Timeline](http://www.beedocs.com/easytimeline/) or [Timeline 3D](http://www.beedocs.com/timeline3D/)

Both of BEEDOCS timeline creation software for Mac will let you import a tab-delimited file (which you could export your Excel file as) into a 2D or 3D timeline.

[image: BEEDOCS Easy Timeline - Event Editor]

You can also include photos, audio, or movies in your events, as well as web links and 3D motion graphics.

### [Aeon Timeline](http://www.scribblecode.com)

You can also create timelines from data using Aeon Timeline:

[image]